# How to match every followed by colon punctuation in Komodo?

Tags: regex, match, komodoedit

In a dialogue (movie script) text file I have to match all the names at the beginning of a sentence followed by the colon punctuation `:`. How do I do this  using Komodo?

Here is a sample text:

> Martin: Let's show Mr. Hooper our, uh, hex. Here. Hooper: Ah, victim identified as Christine Watkins. Female Caucasian. Martin: Yeah now, now here's where we have it. Hooper: Probable boating accident. Martin: Yeah. Hooper: The height and weight of the victim can only be estimated from the partial remains. The torso has been severed in mid-thorax. There are no major organs remai.

Comment: Please add sample text.

Comment: so this is a part f the text below: Normally every line starts with a name (it's a dialogue)

Comment: Martin: Let's show Mr. Hooper our, uh, hex. Here.
Hooper: Ah, victim identified as Christine Watkins. Female Caucasian.
Martin: Yeah now, now here's where we have it.
Hooper: Probable boating accident.
Martin: Yeah.
Hooper: The height and weight of the victim can only be estimated from the
partial remains. The torso has been severed in mid-thorax. There are no major
organs remai..

Comment: Should your sample have line breaks in it? Presently the search you want only would match "Martin", since there is only one line here.

Answer (score 0):

Following regex will find out all names which have `:` after them.

`\s?(\w+)(?=:)`

No matter if dialogues are on seperate lines or they all are on single lines, it will work in both scenarios.

Try above regex at [https://regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/WyPGrE/3).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it with Komodo, but you can separate the output by speakers with the Unix/Linux `sed` command RegEx

```
sed -e "s/\(\w\+\):/\\n\1:/g" text.txt
```

Its output is:

```
Martin: Let's show Mr. Hooper our, uh, hex. Here. 
Hooper: Ah, victim identified as Christine Watkins. Female Caucasian. 
Martin: Yeah now, now here's where we have it. 
Hooper: Probable boating accident. 
Martin: Yeah. 
Hooper: The height and weight of the victim can only be estimated from the partial remains. The torso has been severed in mid-thorax. There are no major organs remai.
```